# Creating APK file inside Android Application on the device?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, apktool

Can one create .APK file from set of files/folder inside Android Application? (for example, inside application like fdroid)

For example, I have uncompressed files of my apk file and I want to recreate/compress it again inside Android application.

Can I use apktool from inside Android Application? Or is there anything similar?

Comment: Note: I want to do this programmatically from inside Android Application while running on the device. I have used apktool before.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible to build an APK on Android, but it won't be easy.  Java supports the ZIP/JAR format natively, so you can assemble the unsigned APK that way.  The only way I know to sign the APK on Android is the *zipsigner* library.  The only maintained copy of that that I've seen is directly included in F-Droid: https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/tree/1.4/app/src/full/java/kellinwood

Answer (score 0):

Apktool cannot run on Android devices. There are incompatibilities with [SnakeYAML](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/591) and Java7 (NIO) features.

I'm not aware of any other tool.